# DateAdd Function on Monthly Basis Looses End-of-Month Information (Microsoft Access)

Tags: ms-access

Let me preface by saying I'm mostly new to VBA and coding in general. My company runs an Access database to keep track of our ~500 storage customers and lots. Each lot has a date paid, date due, and expiry date associated with it that is updated monthly (usually).

We used to just use the Date Picker to select each date manually after pulling up the lot. However, I've created a button that runs the following command:

```
Private Sub Extend_One_Month_Click()
Me.[Date Paid Actual] = Date
Me.[Date_Paid] = DateAdd("m", 1, [Date_Paid])
Me.[Date_Paid_Expiry] = DateAdd("m", 1, [Date_Paid_Expiry])
Me.Recalc
End Sub
```

This works great, for the most part. My issue is that it does not keep any end-of-month information. So, if a customers usual due date is the 29th (or greater) of each month, and I use this function in February, their due date becomes the 28th of each month moving forward (on Access, anyway). Is there any function that will preserve this information?

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, what you haven't explained is the business rules for what *should* apply, and how you know what the customer's normal paid date is?
If you record their normal pay Day of the month then you could use that every month?

Comment: Right. So ideally I press the "+1M" button and it will log when I pressed that button (Date Paid Actual), it will extend what their due date was mean to be (often we have customers that pay early or late), and will finally extend their expiry date to a month from their due date. We have physical files for each customer, and we create a similar log for redundancy. How would I record their normal pay day of each month? @Minty

Comment: Why would a customer's monthly due day change? My bills (utility, cr card, rent) have the same due day regardless of month or when I make payments. You record their normal due day (say the 20th each month) with their customer record. You record actual payments in a Transactions table.

Comment: Then you calculate the due and expiry dates each month when needed, not save to table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My function `DateAddMonth` does exactly that:

```vb
' Returns a date added a number of months.
' Result date is identical to the result of DateAdd("m", Number, Date1)
' except that if an ultimo date of a month is passed, an ultimo date will
' always be returned as well.
' Optionally, days of the 30th (or 28th of February of leap years) will
' also be regarded as ultimo.
'
' Examples:
'   2020-02-28, 1, False -> 2020-03-28
'   2020-02-28, 1, True  -> 2020-03-31
'   2020-02-28,-2, False -> 2019-12-28
'   2020-02-28,-2, True  -> 2019-12-31
'   2020-02-28, 4, False -> 2020-06-28
'   2020-02-28, 4, True  -> 2020-06-30
'   2020-02-29, 4, False -> 2020-06-30
'   2020-06-30, 2, False -> 2020-08-31
'   2020-06-30, 2, True  -> 2020-08-31
'   2020-07-30, 2, False -> 2020-08-30
'   2020-07-30, 1, True  -> 2020-08-31
'
' 2015-11-30. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateAddMonth( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    Number As Double, _
    Optional Include2830 As Boolean) _
    As Date
    
    Dim DateNext    As Date
    
    ' Add number of months the normal way.
    DateNext = DateAdd("m", Number, Date1)
    If Day(Date1) = MaxDayValue Then
        ' Resulting day will be ultimo of the month.
    ElseIf IsDateUltimoMonth(Date1, Include2830) = True Then
        ' Months are added to month ultimo.
        ' Adjust resulting day to be ultimo if not.
        If IsDateUltimoMonth(DateNext, False) = False Then
            ' Resulting day is not ultimo of the month.
            ' Set resulting day to ultimo of the month.
            DateNext = DateThisMonthUltimo(DateNext)
        End If
    End If
    
    DateAddMonth = DateNext
    
End Function
```

It uses a couple of helper functions and constants - too much to post here - which all can be found in my project at **GitHub**:

[VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date)